# Parameter estimation in an ODE system using GEKKO

Tags: python, optimization, ode, least-squares, gekko

I have a system of nonlinear Ordinary Differential Equations that has 3 parameters as inputs: mu, target, and omega. I am trying the estimate these parameters by minimizing the least squared error between my observed values and the output of the ODE system (x5). I have tried different objective functions as well as different IMODES but the solution never converged. Besides, as I always get no solution found error, I cannot see what the closest best parameters are. Do you have any suggestions for my optimization problem? Thanks!

Here is my [yData](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Av3SmoK7Y2Zs9Byqzp7LlcQ3WV-9?e=cizAwB)

My code is:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from gekko import GEKKO
import pickle 

with open('y_observed','rb') as f:
    yData = pickle.load(f)

m = GEKKO()
dt = 0.001
m.time = np.arange(0,1.5,dt)

# Parameters
mu = m.FV(value=0.2, lb=-0.1, ub=1)
omega = m.FV(value=70, lb=0, ub=100)
target = m.FV(value=0.1, lb=-1, ub=3)

# Variables
x1 = m.Var(value=0)
x2 = m.Var(value=0.05)
x3 = m.Var(value=0)
x4 = m.Var(value=0)
x5 = m.Var(value=0.05)
x6 = m.Var(value=0)
y = m.Param(value = yData)
m.Minimize((y-x5)**2)

# Constants 
A = 75
B = 70
C = 45

# ODEs
m.Equation(x1.dt()== 1-x1)
m.Equation(x2.dt()== x3)
m.Equation(x3.dt()== x1*70*(x1*B*0.25*(target-x2) - x3))
m.Equation(x4.dt()== C*(mu - x4))
m.Equation(x5.dt()== A*1.0/np.abs(mu)*(x4 - ((x5-x2)**2 + x6**2))*(x5-x2) - omega*x6)
m.Equation(x6.dt()== A*1.0/np.abs(mu)*(x4 - ((x5-x2)**2 + x6**2))*x6 + omega*(x5-x2))


#Application options
m.options.SOLVER = 3 #APOPT solver
m.options.IMODE = 5 #Dynamic Simultaneous - estimation
m.options.EV_TYPE = 2 #absolute error
#m.options.NODES = 3 #collocation nodes (2,5)

if True:
    mu.STATUS=1
    target.STATUS=1
    omega.STATUS=1

m.solve(disp=True)

print('Objective: ' + str((x5-yData)**2))

print('Solution')
print('mu = ' + str(mu.value[0]))
print('omega = ' + str(omega.value[0]))
print('target = ' + str(target.value[0]))

plt.figure(1)

plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.plot(m.time,x5.value,'k:',LineWidth=2,label=r'$x_5$')
plt.plot(m.time,yData,'b-',LineWidth=2,label=r'$yData$')
plt.ylabel('Value')
plt.legend(loc='best')

plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.plot(m.time,mu.value,'r-',LineWidth=2,label=r'$mu$')
plt.plot(m.time,target.value,'r-',LineWidth=2,label=r'$target$')
plt.plot(m.time,omega.value,'r-',LineWidth=2,label=r'$omega$')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Value')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a Gekko function (`m.abs2()` or `m.abs3()`) for absolute value instead of the Numpy `np.abs()` function.

```py
amu = m.abs3(mu)
```

This requires a switch to the APOPT solver `m.options.SOLVER=1` to ensure that [the Mixed Integer part](https://apmonitor.com/me575/index.php/Main/LogicalConditions) of the model is satisfied. Also, it avoids divide by zero by reformulating your equations as:

```py
m.Equation(amu*x5.dt()== A*(x4 - ((x5-x2)**2 + x6**2))*(x5-x2) - omega*x6)
m.Equation(amu*x6.dt()== A*(x4 - ((x5-x2)**2 + x6**2))*x6 + omega*(x5-x2))
```

The full problem has quite a few variables:

```
 Number of state variables:          47971
 Number of total equations: -        44970
 Number of slack variables: -         5996
 ---------------------------------------
 Degrees of freedom       :          -2995
```

You can ignore the `Warning: DOF <= 0` because not all of the inequality constraints are active. This gives a successful solution that may be a local solution. It may require better parameter initial guess to get global solution such as if you need it to follow the cyclic data.

[image: results]

```
Objective: 260.68493685
Solution
mu = 0.0
omega = 70.0
target = 0.13906027337
```

Here is the full source code with results that use your PKL file for retrieving the data.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from gekko import GEKKO
import pickle 

with open('y_observed.pkl','rb') as f:
    yData = pickle.load(f)

m = GEKKO()
dt = 0.001
m.time = np.arange(0,1.5,dt)

# Parameters
mu = m.FV(value=0.2, lb=-0.1, ub=1)
omega = m.FV(value=70, lb=0, ub=100)
target = m.FV(value=0.1, lb=-1, ub=3)

# Variables
x1 = m.Var(value=0)
x2 = m.Var(value=0.05)
x3 = m.Var(value=0)
x4 = m.Var(value=0)
x5 = m.Var(value=0.05)
x6 = m.Var(value=0)
y = m.Param(value = yData)
m.Minimize((y-x5)**2)

# Constants 
A = 75
B = 70
C = 45

# abs(mu)
amu = m.abs3(mu)

# ODEs
m.Equation(x1.dt()== 1-x1)
m.Equation(x2.dt()== x3)
m.Equation(x3.dt()== x1*70*(x1*B*0.25*(target-x2) - x3))
m.Equation(x4.dt()== C*(mu - x4))
m.Equation(amu*x5.dt()== A*(x4 - ((x5-x2)**2 + x6**2))*(x5-x2) - omega*x6)
m.Equation(amu*x6.dt()== A*(x4 - ((x5-x2)**2 + x6**2))*x6 + omega*(x5-x2))

#Application options
m.options.SOLVER = 1  # APOPT MINLP solver
m.options.IMODE = 5   # Dynamic Simultaneous - estimation
m.options.EV_TYPE = 2 # squared error
m.options.NODES = 3   #collocation nodes (2,5)

if True:
    mu.STATUS=1
    target.STATUS=1
    omega.STATUS=1

m.solve(disp=True)

print('Objective: ' + str(m.options.OBJFCNVAL))

print('Solution')
print('mu = ' + str(mu.value[0]))
print('omega = ' + str(omega.value[0]))
print('target = ' + str(target.value[0]))

plt.figure(1)

plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.plot(m.time,x5.value,'k:',lw=2,label=r'$x_5$')
plt.plot(m.time,yData,'b-',lw=2,label=r'$yData$')
plt.ylabel('Value')
plt.legend(loc='best')

plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.plot(m.time,mu.value,'b-',lw=2,label=r'$mu$')
plt.plot(m.time,target.value,'r--',lw=2,label=r'$target$')
plt.plot(m.time,omega.value,'g:',lw=2,label=r'$omega$')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Value')

plt.show()
```

One of the complicated things about this problem is allowing `mu` to be negative. It is easier to solve if you give it a lower bound of a small number (such as `0.01`) to avoid the `mu=0` solution.

```py
# Parameters
mu = m.FV(value=0.2, lb=0.01, ub=1)
```

```
Objective: 260.68477646
Solution
mu = 0.042062519923
omega = 69.992948651
target = 0.13871376807
```